# Скрыть элемент

Tags: jquery

Всем привет!
Есть код, по клику по ссылке с id=togglere появляется окно div=boxe.
Вопрос, как закрыть этот div кликом мыши в любое место на сайте и так же кликнув по ссылке с id=togglere

```
$('#togglere').click(function(){
    $('#boxe').fadeIn(100);
    $("#story").focus();
    $('#story').val("");
    return false;
          });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы уверены, что закрывать окно нужно по клику в любом месте? В любом - это значит, что и по клику внутри самого окна. Тогда [вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/x9LbT/):

```
var box = $('#boxe');
$('#togglere').(function(e){
    box.fadeToggle();
    return false;
});
$('body').on('click', function(){
    box.fadeOut();
});
```

Если всё-таки клик внутри всплывающего окна не должен приводить к его закрытию, то [немного по-другому](http://jsfiddle.net/x9LbT/1/):

```
var box = $('#boxe');
$('#togglere').click(function(e){
    box.fadeToggle();
    return false;
});
box.on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$('body').on('click', function(){
    box.fadeOut();
});
```